# Comparing 6 dates that is stored in db with the current date

Tags: php, mysql

I am stuck in a query in which I have to compare 6 dates that is stored in the database and I want to compare them with current date.

```
SELECT * 
FROM registration 
WHERE ((( (v1_date)  OR (v2_date) OR (v3_date) OR (v4_date)  OR (v5_date) OR (v6_date) - '$current_date') / 86400) <= 3)
```

Comment: you have one bracket too many for one thing or misplaced. That should've errored out. Kind of giving my head a shake here.

Comment: what database are you working with?  mysql?

Comment: @Fred-ii- no, OPs bracket count appears to balance. although his syntax is still incorrect.

Comment: @Martin yeah you're right, it's confusing. Their `WHERE` clause is off for sure.

Comment: How are these dates stored in your database?

Comment: Hello Rahul, welcome to Stack Overflow. By "Compare" what are you actually looking for as a result? Can you **EDIT** your question to show what sort of answers you would expect as well as what sort of database you are using, how you store your date values and what you've done so far to try and get to your results? cheers

Comment: Sorry guys, it was my mistake of braces.. i am editing it now

Comment: I am using mysql database. time is stored in the format of (122265789)  @devlin carnate , @ CodeGodie @ martin.  please help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

You can't OR the dates together like that - you need to check each date separately and OR the results together. Check out the DATE & DATEDIFF functions to extract the date & compare 2 dates. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

If time format is the Unix time of seconds since midnight 1/1/70, then the FROM_UNIXTIME() function can be used to convert to MySQL format.

```
SELECT * 
FROM registration 
WHERE (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(v1_date))) <=3 ) 
OR (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(v2_date))) <=3 )
....
....
```

Using CURDATE() will get todays date at the server - avoiding any issues with date differences at the client.

Comment: i have saved my date in database as  $Date = strtotime("d-m-y"); could it work or i have to change it as  date("m-d-y");

Comment: The php strtotime function returns the date as seconds since midnight 1/1/70 - which is the unix time - so the MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME function should return the MySQL date/time - as in the modified code above. The DATE function returns just the date portion from date/time & the DATEDIFF function returns the difference between 2 dates.